# What is wrong with my curl command as it is does not seem to be executing?

Tags: curl

am trying to run the below curl command in the MAC Terminal:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'TwilioAccountSID'/Messages.json?To=%Phonenumber&Body=Hello’ -u AccountSID:AuthToken
```

When I press enter it only gives the below:

[image]

Comment: Have you try to remove internal quotes and replace the last (typographic quote) with standard one? `curl -X GET 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/TwilioAccountSID/Messages.json?To=%Phonenumber&Body=Hello' -u AccountSID:AuthToken`

Comment: Thanks. Now it says, command not found -u

[1]  + exit 1     curl -X GET 
zsh: command not found: -u
ichaudhuri@C02CCEPSMD6M ~ %

Comment: Are you sure that curl is installed?

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the quotes:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'TwilioAccountSID'/Messages.json?To=%Phonenumber&Body=Hello’ -u AccountSID:AuthToken
```

correct would be:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/TwilioAccountSID/Messages.json?To=%Phonenumber&Body=Hello' -u 'AccountSID:AuthToken'
```

When you get the error 'command not found', then you missed quotes and the command was parsed as being two commands by the shell.
This often happens when there are `&` in the unquoted URL, which are interpreted by the shell as "execute the part before the `&` as a single command and also execute the part after the `&` as single command".